# Codeigniter 2.1, PHP - count array for requested value in two dimensional array

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have this code:

```
<?php foreach ($galerije as $gal): ?>
<h1><?php echo str_replace('_', ' ', $gal['naziv']) ?></h1>
<p><?php echo word_limiter($gal['opis'], 30) ?></p>
<?php echo count($slike) ?>
<hr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

**$galerija** represent all the galleries in the DB and have **id_galerija** as the primary key.

**$slike** represent all the images in the DB and they have one to many relationship with **galerija** (one gallery can have many images). It is connected with **galerija_id** (**slike.galerija_id = galerija.id_galerija**). How can I count number of images for every gallery?

Comment: Why don't use aggregate function in your database query (COUNT), so you don't need to calculate it manually.

Comment: what is the out put of print_r($slike);

Comment: @SubRed I am not very familiar with MySQL, so I tried to do this the simple way.

Comment: @Sasha it's ok since it's actually based on your need. But it will be better if you left this job to your database server if you have huge data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$galleries = array(array(
    'Galleryname' => 'Picasso',
    'Galleryimages' => array(
        '1.jpg',
        '2.jpg',
        '3.jpg',
        '4.jpg'
        ),
    array(
        '1.jpg',
        '2.jpg'
        ),
    array(
        '1.jpg',
        '2.jpg',
        '3.jpg',
        '4.jpg',
        '5.jpg',
        '6.jpg'
        ),
    ),
array(
    'Galleryname' => 'Matisse',
    'Galleryimages' => array(
        '1.jpg',
        '2.jpg'
        ),
    array(
        '1.jpg',
        '2.jpg',
        '3.jpg'
        ),
    array(
        '1.jpg',
        '2.jpg',
        '3.jpg',
        '4.jpg',
        '5.jpg',
        '6.jpg',
        '7.jpg',
        '8.jpg'
        ),
    )
);

$counts = array();
foreach ($galleries as $key => $value) {
    $counts[$value['Galleryname']] = (count($value, COUNT_RECURSIVE)-count($value)); 
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($counts);
echo '</pre>';
```

Which would end up with:

```
Array
(
    [Picasso] => 12
    [Matisse] => 13
)
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Furthermore: You really shouldn't do all this logic in your view, instead you could make a helper function for the recursive count and do it in your controller, and send that variable to your view from there.

Answer (score -2):

wrap it

i is the count

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($Contents as $item) {
    $i++;
    $item[number];
}
```

Comment: What is the second statement in the foreach loop doing? `number` is undefined.

Comment: second statement?  this is very straight forward code, and the solution that was marked as correct is essentially doing the same thing I just demonstrated to you.  you can't expect the right answers posted to be the actual code... you need to follow the pattern and implement to your own code.

Comment: you are taking responses too literal.  i didn't code your solution, I provided you a pattern that you can implement with your code.  $i is set to 0, and incremented with $i++ for each time the foreach loop is run.

Comment: FYI, I'm not the guy who asked the question.